# React-Native-Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native

I tried [this solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384733/react-native-could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath) but didn't work.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Android-Studio-3, Java-1.8,
Gradle-3.4.1.

[Github-repo link](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/goods-seller/)  of my project. 
I am building React-Native App, after `npm run eject`, I can't run `npm run android`.

I was able to run a [project](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/goods-seller/) before ejecting app
but an error occurs when I run `npm run android`,

```
(base) gd@gd10:~/Desktop/react-native/demo_app$ npm run android

> @ android /home/gd/Desktop/react-native/demo_app
> react-native run-android

Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/gd/Desktop/react-native/demo_app/node_modules (9ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/3.1.2/gradle-do
wnload-task-3.1.2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-
4.4.4.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.4.
4/httpcomponents-core-4.4.4.pom

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'goods_seller'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

It fails to build gradle, and could not find gradle, though I have installed gradle using `sudo apt-get install gradle`.

It gives same output on running with flag `--stactrace`,

`gradle -v` output is

```
(base) gd@gd10:~/Desktop/react-native/demo_app$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2012-12-21 00:00:00 UTC
Revision:     none

Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.3 compiled on July 19 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-45-generic amd64

(base) gd@gd10:~/Desktop/react-native/demo_app$
```

`demo_app/android/build.gradle` file is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 24
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    // gradleVersion = '4.10.3'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

**Edit 1:**

after answer from [cod-e-rection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8856315/cod-e-rection),

I changed code as

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
}
```

then after running `npm run android`,
it gave error as,

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/gd/Desktop/react-native/demo_app/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think it should be `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'` or same as current Android Studio version number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1.` issue is solved by changing the version code `3.4.1` to `3.3.2`.

Another problem exists because in `3.3.2` gradle version you have to use minimum gradle distribution version `4.10.1`. To solve this open `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and use this line to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Replace the previous on whatever it is.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The latest android gradle version is :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
}
```

You can find the documentation at the follwing [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)
. So you have to change it from `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'` to : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'` and it will be fixed.

Comment: thanks @cod-e-rection, It didn't work. I have updated question after trying this answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` change `distributionUrl` to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Then, in `android/build.gradle` change gradle classpath to this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```